# Sum rows if another list of rows has a specific value (lists are not equal size)

Tags: excel, sum, criteria

I'll try to explain my question, couldn't find an answer anywhere because it's hard to formulate.

Lets say we have a list of costs and sub-costs (more detailed breakdown of the costs).  Also, we have a list of only costs (it's shorter than the previous one, because contains only costs, without sub-costs). The second list has values TRUE or FALSE. I want to sum all costs from the first list that have TRUE value in the second list. SUMIF won't work because lists are not equal sized.

An example is on the picture. The sum must be 8 (because A and C are TRUE on the second list).

[image]

Comment: **a** and **b** are **NOT** true on the second list. See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Comment: Don't get what you are talking about. I need to sum cells B3 and B8 because A and C in the second list are marked as true. If user makes B TRUE, formula should also add B5, i.e. the result is 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula¹ in an appropriate cell.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B, A:A, IF(H1:H3, G1:G3)))
```

[image: sum_sumifs_if_array_formula]

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type the braces in yourself. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

<sub>[Sample in cloud](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Sum%20rows%20if%20another%20list%20of%20rows%20has%20a%20specific%20value.xlsx)</sub>

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The answer with a helper column and lookup works as well, but this array-solution is more concise and effective.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the aid of a helper column.  In `C1` put `=VLOOKUP(A1,$G:$H,2,0)` and copy down.

Then your sum becomes `=SUMIF(C:C,TRUE,B:B)`